# SwiftUI: independent view layers

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm trying to creating a floating button on the bottom right of the screen. The way I'm doing my floating view is like this

```
ZStack {
    the_underneath_view
    the_floating_button (matches the dimensions of the the_underneath_view)
}
```

It works fine with a non-scrollable `the_underneath_view` view. However, when I introduce ScrollView into the picture, things get ugly. The button is now pushed to the bottom of the scroll view which is outside of the screen.

How to make these 2 layers independent from each other; in UIKit, we can use UIWindow. I would prefer something pure SwiftUI and not the UIViewRepresentable.

Thanks

**UADATE:**
I actually wrap the whole thing in another ZStack during my call stack without realizing it. After removing the excessive outmost ZStack, everything works fine now.

Comment: Would you provide minimal reproducible example (to avoid guessing)?

Comment: As mentioned in the previous comment, a bit of code could be a good starting point, otherwise we'll have to base our answers on our our widely different assumptions :). My guess is, you have "the_underneath_view", which you wan to scroll and the_floating_button that you want to be on top of it in the bottom right corner. Would something like this do: ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) { ScrollView { the_underneath_view } the_floating_button  }?

Comment: I was dumb, I actually wrap the whole thing in another ZStack without realizing it. After removing the excessive outmost ZStack, it works fine now. Thanks for trying to help silly me. :D